# Connect to Firebase Functions through static IP address

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, static-ip-address

I need my API to be whitelisted in a client's server so my Firebase Functions must have a public static IP address.
So I created a Google VPC connector/Gateway/Cloud NAT to associate a static IP address to my Firebase Function. Everything has been configured properly but I am unable to connect to my function through the given public IP address.

I'm trying to reach it through **https://PUBLIC_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS/cloudFunction** (for example https://123.123.123.123/v1) but it just does not work. It hangs.
I know the IP address is correct because I get a response by pinging it.

Which is the proper way to reach a cloud function through its public IP after associating it to a connector?

Comment: As containers are spun up and down as needed, it is not possible to get a static IP address for Cloud Functions.